# How to thank a potential supervisor's email?

Tags: phd, application, professorship

I have recently interviewed by a professor in US after sending him my CV. A few days after the interview he mailed me and told me to do the formal application process and mention him as the professor I want to work with.
Now, I want to thank him for considering me as a choice of his future PhD student. What should I write?

Comment: Thank you? You’ve written thank you notes before, right?

Answer (score 2):

Do not overthink this (and do not write a very long text). Just write

> Dear Prof. NAME,
>
> Thank you very much for considering me as a PhD student.
>
> Best, NAME

Comment: Do you think when he has told me to apply. It means he has accepted me as his student?

Comment: I got the impression from your question that he did - what do you mean by "considering me as a choice of his future PhD student"? Are you his choice?

Comment: You can can add "I am looking forward to working in your lab" (or "working with you" if it is not experimental domain).

Comment: @Alireza it sounds like you're not quite accepted yet. While the professor sounds willing to supervise you, you have been told to make a formal application, which could still be rejected (especially if the department cannot find funding for you). Having a prof on your side certainly helps, though :) Also, don't know why this answer was downvoted, it's good advice imo.